# Can't upgrade heroku postgres from hobby tier to standard

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I followed this guide in order to upgrade the plan for postgres:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/updating-heroku-postgres-databases#updating-with-addons-upgrade

I want to upgrade using `heroku addons:upgrade`.

this is the output:

```
Changing postgresql-rernd-166744 on myapp-api from heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev to heroku-postgresql:standard-0... !
 !    An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to change to heroku-postgresql:standard-0:
 !    heroku-postgresql does not currently support changing plans.
```

I have added a bank card and already using another heroku plan in another app so I doubt that's the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any upgrade regarding Hobby plan, you have to use `pg:copy`, `heroku addons:upgrade` only work for production tier (new and old database must be on those plans)

Answer (score 4):

> The pg:copy command supports updates between all supported Heroku
> Postgres plans and versions. Additionally, it is the only supported
> method for updates involving a Hobby-tier database (whether you are
> migrating to one or from one).

So this is the guide you want to follow in order to upgrade your DB plan

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrading-with-pg-copy